# Can't set up or access email in new google apps?

Tags: google-workspace, gmail

I've set up google apps accounts many times before, and run into anything like this. Today I just set up a new google apps account, and have been going through the usual steps of setting up the domain settings. Usually, when you click on email, it has you set up mx records on your registrar. However, if I click on 'set up email', all it does is take me to the mobile setup tab. I can't figure out any way to access the actual inbox or instructions for setting up mx records. It's maddening. Anyone have a clue?

[image]

**Takes me here ->**

[image]

Comment: You're stuck in the new setup wizard, either skip through it or hit one of the tabs at the top and navigate back. It's yet another great example of google's crap IA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add these records:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174125

or
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33915

Hopefully that will fix your issues.

Comment: Thanks for the links mesh- just don't understand why Google Apps wasn't divulging that info.